# How to show ad banner depends on datetime?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a small algorithm to show an ad inside a container that contains a three banners but not to show all of them at once, I want to show just one every day.

Lets say each banner have to appear at a certain date time as showing bellow in the list:

```
ads = [
    {   
        'banner': f'{ads_path}/1/ad_1917_175.gif',
        'dtime': datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)
    },
    {
        'banner': f'{ads_path}/2/ad_1917x175.gif',
        'dtime': datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2)
    },
    {
        'banner': f'{ads_path}/3/ad_1917x175_2.gif',
        'dtime': datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=3)
    }
]
```

all banners are saved inside database where I can filter each one by it offset, also I've created a `datetime.now()` variable to compare it with the dtime in my query, something like this:

```
dtime_now = datetime.now()
get_banner = Ads.query.filter(Ads.dtime < dtime_now).offset(1).limit(1)
```

From here I want to start, and the iteration will go to first banner if all dates inside database are smaller than the current time.

```
dtimes = [datetime.strptime(str(item.dtime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') for item in get_ads]`
```

I've tried to combine the list of all **dtimes** to get them all in one **datetime** object, then to look if the result is smaller than the current time, that means go to first banner change it **dtime** and show it and so on.

But Python won't let you do that, because it just combines `timedelta`.

Any suggestions how to make that work? what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm following your logic, but you don't need a database to do this.  How about:

```
ad_change_times = [datetime_1, datetime_2, datetime_3]

for i in range(len(ad_change_times)): # or range(1, len(ad_change_times)+1) if you insist on counting from 1
  if datetime.now() > ad_change_times[i]:
    banner = f'{ads_path}/{i}/ad_1917_175.gif',
    break
```

Then, send that to your template.

Comment: Will! logic is very close! I need to create an iteration through them to show every banner in a specific day! `timedelta(minutes=1)` is just an example, in fact I want to make each one to appear every day so `timedelta(days=1)` and so on until the end of the month lets say for instance. The reason why I am using database is that because, I don't want the planned date time to get changed every time a request sends to the server, I prefer to save as static value before it get changed if date time have passed so I can give it a new value for another minute

Comment: In my code, `ad_change_times` is static.  You can hard code it.  Or, you can store in db and query to get the ad change days. e.g.: `datetime_1 = datetime(2020,9,10), datetime_2 = datetime(2020,9,11)`, etc

Comment: Ooooh yeah! thanks mate), I thought I would end up with at least  ten lines of code, it is really a miss that I have right now in my VSCode just trying random stuff with logic that I have. Thank you again really helped a lot, I will add some robust stuff based on that :)